# Am I using ForeignKey correctly in this scenario?

Tags: django

I am wondering if I am designing my database correctly.  I have a "Credit" table "TransferRequest" table. Users can request Credit to be transferred. I want to track with which transfer the credit went.

So I added this field my Credit table to be able to assign the transfer ID to the credit field when a transfer is initiated.

`transfer_request = models.ForeignKey(TransferRequest, null=True, blank=True, default=None)`

I am wondering if this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct, except you'll want to remove the `default=None` which is implied with foreign keys, and in your case `null=True` means that you can simply leave the field blank and submit without a problem. Also, see [`on_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) for null foreign key fields.